# How to create Regex for 00.00?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex which validate the all below conditions. Only numeric [0-9] value allow.

- 00.00
- 0.00
- 00.0
- 0.0
- 00
- 0

Comment: don't forget to post your attempts at very first.

Comment: `^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}$`

Comment: Only two digit allow before and after `.` . but your regex not validate the max 2 digit. @Avinash

Comment: Thank you Tushar. its working..

Comment: Then you should state that 2-digit limit in your question.

Comment: @DanielBleisteiner Unless the examples in the question weren't there before there was no indication I received that there could be more than (2) digits; I interpreted the question as a (2) digit max.

Comment: The question has been edited indeed... but not improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comment of OP/modified question, if you want 1 or 2 digits, optionally followed by (a period, followed by 1 or 2 more digits), you could use this regex:

```
var regex = /^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
// The ( ) groups several things together sequentially.
// The ? makes it optional.
```

---

If you want 1 or 2 digits, followed by a period, followed by 1 or 2 more digits:

```
var regex = /^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/;
// The / denotes the start and end of the regex.
// The ^ denotes the start of the string.
// The $ denotes the end of the string.
// The \d denotes the class of digit characters.
// The {1,2} denotes to match 1 to 2 occurrences of what was encountered immediately to the left.
// The \. denotes to match an actual . character; normally . by itself is a wildcard.

// happy paths
regex.test('00.00'); // true
regex.test('0.00'); // true
regex.test('00.0'); // true
regex.test('0.0'); // true
regex.test('12.34'); // true (test other digits than '0')

// first half malformed
regex.test('a0.00'); // non-digit in first half
regex.test('.00'); // missing first digit
regex.test('000.00'); // too many digits in first half

// period malformed
regex.test('0000'); // missing period
regex.test('00..00'); // extra period

// second half malformed
regex.test('00.a0'); // non-digit in second half
regex.test('00.'); // missing last digit
regex.test('00.000'); // too many digits in second half
```

Comment: If conditions are `00.00`, `0.00`, `00.0`, `0.0`, and `00` or `0`.  ?

Comment: @MukeshDhama That's different than your question.

Answer (score 1):

To match 1 or more  zeros on both sides of the dot you may use the `+` operator. And because the dot has a special meaning you'll have to quote it. `0+\.0+` should do that job.

To match any digit you may use `\d+\.\d+`...

And to limit it to max 2 digits use `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}`.